# Elegant Polling for Thread Interrupts

Tags: java, thread-safety

I know there a couple of related questions, but I was unable to find a clear answer. [Java recommends](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html) to catch Interrupt Exceptions as the follows:

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(4000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // We've been interrupted: no more messages.
    return;
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to catch an interrupt - I want to avoid these try/catach statements all the time and I want to exit my code as fast as possible if an interrupt occurs.

Comment: Well you don't want `Thread.sleep()` in the first place.

Comment: I want to have both, sleeps as well as usual commands. If a Interrupt occurs I want to exit immediatly - afterwards I execute a cleaning program in another thread